# Alignment of numbers on the individual bars with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to show numbers on the individuals bars in the following graph.

```
df <- structure(list(A = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L,
3L), .Label = c("0-50,000", "50,001-250,000", "250,001-Over"), class = "factor"),
    B = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("0-50,000",
    "50,001-250,000", "250,001-Over"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(0.507713884992987,
    0.258064516129032, 0.23422159887798, 0.168539325842697, 0.525280898876405,
    0.306179775280899, 0.160958904109589, 0.243150684931507,
    0.595890410958904)), .Names = c("A", "B", "Freq"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-9L))

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=A, y=Freq))+
            geom_bar(aes(fill=B), position=position_dodge()) + theme_bw()
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(formatter="percent")
p <- p + geom_text(aes(label = paste(sprintf("%.1f", Freq*100), "%", sep=""), y = Freq+0.015, x=A), size = 3)
print(p)
```

[image]

I could not figure out how to put the numbers in the right position along x-axis. Any help will be highly appreciates. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add `position=position_dodge(width=0.9)` to the geom_text call.

Cleaning up your code a little gives:

```
p <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=A, y=Freq))+
    geom_bar(aes(fill=B), position = position_dodge()) + 
    geom_text(aes(label = paste(sprintf("%.1f", Freq*100), "%", sep=""),
                  y = Freq+0.015, x=A),
              size = 3, position = position_dodge(width=0.9)) +
    scale_y_continuous(formatter = "percent") +
    theme_bw()
```

which results in

[image]

Comment: @MYaseen208 Thanks for the completely reproducible question including data.  Makes answering (well, checking that my answer was right) much easier.

Comment: Update to this answer for ggplot2 0.9.0 is at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10113480/892313