# Alignment of numbers on the individual bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have the need to place labels above bars on ggplot.  I used to use the method found ([HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184969/alignment-of-numbers-on-the-individual-bars-with-ggplot2/9185168#9185168)) but this does not appear to work anymore since my ggplot2 update as I now get the error message:

```
Error in continuous_scale(c("y", "ymin", "ymax", "yend", "yintercept",  : 
  unused argument(s) (formatter = "percent")
```

How can I again plot numeric values above the bars when using the example:

```
df <- structure(list(A = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L,
3L), .Label = c("0-50,000", "50,001-250,000", "250,001-Over"), class = "factor"),
    B = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("0-50,000",
    "50,001-250,000", "250,001-Over"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(0.507713884992987,
    0.258064516129032, 0.23422159887798, 0.168539325842697, 0.525280898876405,
    0.306179775280899, 0.160958904109589, 0.243150684931507,
    0.595890410958904)), .Names = c("A", "B", "Freq"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-9L))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=A, y=Freq))+
    geom_bar(aes(fill=B), position = position_dodge()) + 
    geom_text(aes(label = paste(sprintf("%.1f", Freq*100), "%", sep=""),
                  y = Freq+0.015, x=A),
              size = 3, position = position_dodge(width=0.9)) +
    scale_y_continuous(formatter = "percent") +
    theme_bw()
```

Running R 2.15 ggplot2 0.9 on a win 7 machine

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The error is from the `scale_y_continuous` call. Formatting of labels is now handled by the `labels` argument. See the [ggplot2 0.9.0 transition guide](https://github.com/downloads/hadley/ggplot2/guide-col.pdf) for more details.

There was another problem with the labels not lining up correctly; I fixed that by adding a `group=B` to the aesthetics for the `geom_text`; I'm not quite sure why this is necessary, though. I also took out `x=A` from the `geom_text` aesthetics because it was not needed (it would be inherited from the `ggplot` call.

```
library("ggplot2")
library("scales")

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=A, y=Freq))+
    geom_bar(aes(fill=B), position = position_dodge()) + 
    geom_text(aes(label = paste(sprintf("%.1f", Freq*100), "%", sep=""),
                  y = Freq+0.015, group=B),
              size = 3, position = position_dodge(width=0.9)) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Dang I had tried labels ="percent" (as I checked out `? scale_y_continuous`) but didn't try without quotation marks. So close but so far. T hanks Brian.

Comment: Not only do you not need the quotes, but the formatting functions are now in the `scales` package, so that has to also be loaded.