# How to fix plot labels from appearing above one bar in grouped plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I made a grouped bar plot in ggplot and I want to label each bar with the number_of_systems. The labels show up but they all appear over the middle bar, reporting_systems B, in the group. How can I edit geom_text to get the labels to appear over their appropriate bars?

```
data1 <- data.frame(office = c("HR","HR","HR","Comms","Comms","Comms","Legal","Legal","Legal","Accounting","Accounting","Accounting","Admin","Admin","Admin","Policy","Policy","Policy","Research","Research","Research"), reporting_systems = c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C"), number_of_systems = c(27,0,0,12,1,4,15,2,15,29,0,0,2,0,0,59,28,46,0,0,0))

reporting_order <- factor(data$reporting_systems, level = c("A","B","C"))

ggplot(data = data1, aes(x = office, y = number_of_systems, fill = reporting_order)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Number of Projects") +
  ggtitle("") +
  geom_text(aes(label = number_of_systems, fill = reporting_order), vjust = -0.3, color = "black", size = 4) +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(color = "black"), 
        axis.text = element_text(color = "black", size = 15),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 35, hjust = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 1), axis.title.y = (element_text(size = 15)),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA, size = 0.5),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA), text = element_text(size = 15))
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a very similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37587288/ggplot-label-bars-in-grouped-bar-plot).

The answer is to add a position parameter to your geom_text:

```
ggplot(data = data1, aes(x = office, y = number_of_systems, fill = reporting_order)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Number of Projects") +
  ggtitle("") +
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width=0.9), aes(label = number_of_systems, fill = reporting_order), vjust = -0.3, color = "black", size = 4) +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(color = "black"), 
        axis.text = element_text(color = "black", size = 15),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 35, hjust = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 1), axis.title.y = (element_text(size = 15)),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA, size = 0.5),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA), text = element_text(size = 15))
```