# How to annotate geom_bar above bars?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to do a simple plot using ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut, y = depth)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "blue") +
  facet_wrap(~ color) +
  geom_text(aes(x = cut, y = depth, label = cut, vjust = 0))
```

[image: ggplot2 plot]

How can I annotate this plot so that I get annotations above bars? Now geom_text puts labels at the bottom of the bars, but I want them above these bars.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112587/re-alignment-of-numbers-on-the-individual-bars-with-ggplot2

Comment: @jrara if i knew this to be the final version, I would export the plot and annotate in a program like publisher.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `stat_summary()` to calculate position of `y` values as sum of `depth` and use `geom="text"` to add labels. The sum is used because your bars shows the sum of `depth` values for each `cut` value.

As suggest by @joran it is better to use `stat_summary()` instead of `geom_bar()` to show sums of y values because `stat="identity"` makes problems due to overplotting of bars and if there will be negative values then bar will start in negative part of plot and end in positive part - result will be not the actual sum of values.

```
ggplot(diamonds[1:100,], aes(x = cut, y = depth)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ color) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = sum, geom="bar", fill = "blue", aes(label=cut, vjust = 0)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = sum, geom="text", aes(label=cut), vjust = 0)
```

[image]

You can also precalculate sum of depth values and the you can use `geom_bar()` with `stat="identity"` and `geom_text()`.

```
library(plyr)
diamonds2<-ddply(diamonds,.(cut,color),summarise,depth=sum(depth))

ggplot(diamonds2,aes(x=cut,y=depth))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",fill="blue")+
  geom_text(aes(label=cut),vjust=0,angle=45,hjust=0)+
  facet_wrap(~color)
```

Comment: I was confused at first because they are using `color` for the bars rather than `fill` and overplotting thousands of them because of `stat = "identity"`. They look solid, but I think that's an illusion because there are so many of them. Not sure if that was intended or not...

Comment: Yes, if you subset first 100 rows of diamonds it can be seen that bars consist of many small parts with blue outline. I think OP should clarify this.

Comment: Yes, that was unintentional, what is the correct way to create this graph? Maybe using stat_summary and geom_text?

Comment: @DidzisElferts sum of depth values

Comment: @DidzisElferts I suggest that you rotate the text.

Comment: @jara ...but for the sum of the depth values, you can't use `stat = "identity"`. Either replace `geom_bar` with another `stat_summary` or aggregate the data ahead of time. You're still getting the sum sort of by accident due to overplotting.

Comment: @joran yes, that is what I understood from you first comment. I'm trying to do that.

Comment: This seems to work: 
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = cut, y = depth)) +
  facet_wrap(~ color) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = sum, geom="bar", fill = "blue", aes(label=cut, vjust = 0)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = sum, geom="text", aes(label=cut), vjust = 0)

Comment: @joran Updated my answer - didn't notice the problem with stat="identity" because it gives the same result as with stat_summary().