# How can I make a Frequency distribution bar plot in ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Sample of the dataset.

```
nq
0.140843018
0.152855833
0.193245919
0.156860105
0.171658019
0.186281942
0.290739146
0.162779517
0.164694042
0.171658019
0.195866609
0.166967913
0.136841748
0.108907644
0.264136384
0.356655651
0.250508305
```

I would like to make a Percentage Bar plot/Histogram like this question: [RE: Alignment of numbers on the individual bars with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112587/re-alignment-of-numbers-on-the-individual-bars-with-ggplot2/10113480#10113480)

The max value of NQ for full dataset is 21 and minimum value is  0.00005

But I am unable to adapt the code as I don't have a Freq column and I have one series.

I have made a mockup of the figure I am trying to make.[image]

Could you please help?

Comment: You want number of cases or the percentage in your y scale?

Comment: @DavidArenburg No. of Cases in y-axis. % on top of the bar. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would that work for you?

```
nq <- read.table(text = "
0.140843018
0.152855833
0.193245919
0.156860105
0.171658019
0.186281942
0.290739146
0.162779517
0.164694042
0.171658019
0.195866609
0.166967913
0.136841748
0.108907644
0.264136384
0.356655651
0.250508305", header = F) # Your data

nq$V2 <- cut(nq$V1, 5, include.lowest = T)
nq2 <- aggregate(V1 ~ V2, nq, length)
nq2$V3 <- nq2$V1/sum(nq2$V1)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + geom_bar(data = nq2, aes(V2, V1), stat = "identity", width=1, fill = "white", col = "black", size = 2) + 
  geom_text(vjust=1, fontface="bold", data = nq2, aes(label = paste(sprintf("%.1f", V3*100), "%", sep=""), x = V2,  y = V1 + 0.4), size = 5) + 
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0,0), labels = sprintf("%.3f",seq(min(nq$V1), max(nq$V1), by = max(nq$V1)/6))) +
  ylab("No. of Cases") + xlab("") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold", angle = 0), 
    panel.grid.major = element_blank() ,
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank() ,
    panel.border = element_blank() ,
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_line(color = 'black', size = 2),
    axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold")
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. What is V1 here? In my problem, nq is a column inside a dataframe and I reference it as df$nq.

Comment: See my edit, I've loaded your data as data frame, You can modify it properly with your data afterwords.

Comment: Yes, getting it now. Modifying.

Answer (score 0):

I thought this would be easy, but it turned out to be frustrating. So perhaps the "right" way is to transform your data before using `ggplot` as it looks like @DavidArenburg has done. But, if you feel like hacking `ggplot`, here's what I ended up doing.

First, some sample data.

```
set.seed(15)
dd<-data.frame(x=sample(1:25, 100, replace=T, prob=25:1))
br <- seq(0,25, by=5) # break points
```

My first attempt was

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dd, aes(x)) + 
    stat_bin(position="stack", breaks=br) + 
    geom_text(aes(y=..count.., label=..density..*..width.., ymax=..count..+1), 
        vjust=-.5, breaks=br, stat="bin")
```

but that didn't make "pretty labels"

[image]

so i thought i'd use the `percent()` function from the `scales` package to make it pretty. However, silly `ggplot` doesn't really make it possible to use functions with `..()..` variables because it evaluates them in the data.frame only (then the empty `baseenv()`). It doesn't have a way to find the function you use. So this is when I turned to hacking. First i'll extract the "Layer" definition from ggplot and the `map_statistic` from it. (**NOTE**: this was done with "ggplot2_1.0.0" and is specific to that version; this is a private function that may change in future releases)

```
orig.map_statistic <- ggplot2:::Layer$map_statistic
new.map_statistic <- orig.map_statistic
body(new.map_statistic)[[9]]
# stat_data <- as.data.frame(lapply(new, eval, data, baseenv()))
```

here's the line that's causing grief I would prefer it the function resolved other names in the plot environment that are not found in the data.frame. So I decided to change it with

```
body(new.map_statistic)[[9]] <- quote(stat_data <- as.data.frame(lapply(new, eval, data, plot$plot_env)))
assign("map_statistic", new.map_statistic, envir=ggplot2:::Layer)
```

So now I can use functions with `..()..` variables. So I can do

```
library(scales)
ggplot(dd, aes(x)) + 
    stat_bin(position="stack", breaks=br) + 
    geom_text(aes(y=..count.., ymax=..count..+2, 
        label=percent(..density..*..width..)), 
        vjust=-.5, breaks=br, stat="bin")
```

to get

[image]

So i'm not sure why `ggplot` has this default behavior. There could be some good reason for it but I don't know what it is. This does change how `ggplot` will behave for the rest of the session. You can change back to default with

```
assign("map_statistic", orig.map_statistic, envir=ggplot2:::Layer)
```

Comment: Perhaps @hadley might be able to explain why it only searches the calculated data.frame and doesn't continue searching in the plot environment.