# object not found error in R when trying to use a command line argument

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried to pass a number on a command line to a very simple R script to do some plotting.

I got this plot.r file:

```
args<-commandArgs(TRUE)

vmcn<-as.integer(args[1])

library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

file<-read.table("my file.txt",header=F)

ggplot(file,aes(x=V1))+geom_histogram(binwidth=1,aes(y=..count../vmcn*100))+theme_bw()

ggsave(filename="myfile.pdf",width=4,height=4)
```

When I run it this way:

```
Rscript plot.r 5000
```

I got the error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'vmcn' not found
Calls: print ... <Anonymous> -> as.data.frame -> lapply -> FUN -> eval
Execution halted
```

Can someone enlighten me on what's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This actually has nothing to do with the fact that you run R via command line. Your script also doesn't work interactively. This is to do with the way the `aes` function of `ggplot2` searches for your objects. Rather surprisingly, it does not by default search in the global environment. Here's how you fix it:

```
# some reproducible data 
set.seed(1)
vmcn <- 100
file <- data.frame(V1 = rnorm(1000))
# and the fixed plotting command 
ggplot(file, aes(x=V1)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=1, aes(y=..count..*100/get("vmcn", envir=.GlobalEnv))) +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: it worked! thanks for the answer, i learned something about R again.

Comment: I ran into [this problem before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24538031/how-can-i-make-a-frequency-distribution-bar-plot-in-ggplot2/24541345#24541345) as well. It seems to only happen with aesthetics where you use the special `..var..` variables.