# Scales comma() function not working within geom_text()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

After running the following code, I receive the error:

> Error in comma(count) : could not find function "comma"

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(xvar, fill=yvar)) + 
  geom_bar(alpha = 0.7) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 14000, by=1000), label = comma) +
  labs(title="title", x="xlab", y="ylab") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("gold2", "forestgreen", "dimgrey")) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'gray95'),
        title = element_text(face = "bold.italic", color = "black"),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))  +
  geom_text(stat = "count", 
            aes(label = comma(..count..)), 
            size = 4,
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.50))
```

Once I remove the `comma()` function from within `geom_text()`, the code runs fine and produces the graph I want, except the data labels are not in comma format. I  have the 'scales' package loaded and even use `label = comma` in the `scale_y_continuous()` line. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What version of `ggplot2` are you using? You can check with `sessionInfo()`. Also when asking for help, it's very helpful to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @BenBolker ; i deleted comments as the question notes that scales is loaded. @Chief ; just to confirm you have used `library(scales)`

Comment: is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027288/error-could-not-find-function-in-r helpful/a duplicate?

Comment: @BenBolker That could be a duplicate, but there was an issue with ggplot and using the `..` variables in that it executed them in an empty environment so you couldn't use functions in connections with them. I thought that was only in an older ggplot versions but maybe it persists. So it may be a unique situation given that `comma` works with the `scale_y_continuous` in the same plot.

Comment: can't reproduce; if I run `mydata <- data.frame(xvar=1:3,yvar=factor(1:3)); library(ggplot2);
library(scales)` and then your code, I get a (trivial) plot (ggplot2 version 3.0.0)

Comment: This is where I had faced a similar problem in the past: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24538031/how-can-i-make-a-frequency-distribution-bar-plot-in-ggplot2/24541345#24541345 (but that was ggplot2_1.0.0)

Comment: @MrFlick I'm using  ggplot2_2.2.1, is that too old? How do I update a package? I'd love to create a reproducible example, but I'm still new to R and unfamiliar with the commands for generating random samples / creating data frames. I'm just importing datasets I've already cleaned in SAS.

Comment: The original comment I left had a link with ways to create a reproducible example. Using something like `dput()` is usually most effective. You can usually just update a package by installing it again. `install.packages("ggplot2")`

Comment: @user20650 I have already ran library(scales).

Comment: @MrFlick It seems the fix was as simple as updating to the newest version of R and ggplot2 (hindsight 20/20). Thanks for the help, I'll be sure to create a reproducible example next time.