# ggplot2 Bar Chart Formatting

Tags: r, ggplot2, format, bar-chart

I have been trying to get the following code, which produces Image 1, to look like Image 2, I would very much appreciate any help!

```
barchart = ggplot(
  data = Final_tank, 
  aes(x = Lookback, y = Return, fill = Type)) +
geom_bar(aes(fill = Type), position = "dodge", stat="identity") + 
guides(
  fill = guide_legend(
    reverse = FALSE, 
    keywidth = 2, 
    keyheight = 2,
    nrow = nrow(Final_tank),
    labels = Final_tank$Category, 
    title = (NULL))) +  
scale_fill_manual(values = c("#002142", "#e8a823", "#afafaf")) +  
scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
```

Image 1
[image]

Image 2
[image]

Comment: Can you please provide the or some data using dput?

Comment: `... + theme_classic()`

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10112587/903061) for one of many questions for labeling ggplot2 bars

Answer (score 0):

For the x-axis to show up in the order you want it to, you'll have to modify the data:

```
data %>% mutate(Lookback = fct_relevel(Lookback, c("Since Inception", "5 Year", ...)
```

For the rest:

```
+    
geom_text(aes(label = Return,
                      y = Return+0.015, x=Lookback),
                  size = 3, position = position_dodge(width=0.9)) +
        scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)+
        theme_bw()
```