# adding ID to outliers in ggplot barplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, outliers

I have created a stacked barplot

```
ggplot(data %>% count(x, y),
        aes(x, n, fill = factor(y))) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity")+
theme_light()+
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5))
```

[image]

there are (possible) outliers at 50,54 and 60. How can I add their ID into the graph?

Comment: How do you want to decide a value is an outlier? Anything above a set threshold, more than x number of standard deviations from mean, etc.

Comment: I basically want to add ID to the values at x-axis at 50,54 and 60. I managed to do it manually, but it is inefficient. The distribution has mean 31.86 and sd 6.07 - so the threshold would be more than 3 standard deviations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you post your data, I'll amend this answer using it. But basically you want

```
df %>%
    count(x, y) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = x, y = n, fill = y)) +
    geom_col() +
    geom_text(aes(label = x), data = . %>% filter(x >= thresh), vjust = 0, nudge_y = 0.1)
```

where `thresh` is some threshold you've set--maybe an arbitrary cutoff point that makes sense, or maybe 3 standard deviations from the mean of x, or whatever. You can store it in an outside variable, you can make a boolean column in your dataframe, or you can calculate it inline inside your `geom_text`--really up to you. `vjust = 0, nudge_y = 0.1` puts the labels just above the bars corresponding to your outliers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe geom_text(data=mydata%>%filter(just.the.outliers) ?
See also this: [RE: Alignment of numbers on the individual bars with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10112587/re-alignment-of-numbers-on-the-individual-bars-with-ggplot2)