# Annotation above bars:

Tags: r, ggplot2

dodged bar plot in ggplot again has me stumped.  I asked about annotating text above bars on here a few weeks back ([LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815226/annotate-values-above-bars-ggplot-faceted)) and got a terrific response to use `+ stat_bin(geom="text", aes(label=..count.., vjust=-1))`.  I figured since I already have the counts I'll just supply them with out the `..` before and after and I told `stat_bin` that the `position` was `dodge`.  It lines them up over the center of the group and adjusts up and down.  Probably something minor.  Please help me to get the text over the bars.

[image]

```
mtcars2 <- data.frame(type=factor(mtcars$cyl), 
    group=factor(mtcars$gear))
library(plyr); library(ggplot)
dat <- rbind(ddply(mtcars2,.(type,group), summarise,
    count = length(group)),c(8,4,NA))

p2 <- ggplot(dat,aes(x = type,y = count,fill = group)) + 
    geom_bar(colour = "black",position = "dodge",stat = "identity") +
    stat_bin(geom="text", aes(position='dodge', label=count, vjust=-.6))
```

Comment: Have a look on this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9184969/707145).

Comment: This works MYaseen but Marius's is a little more easily understood. +1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was having trouble getting the position dodges to line up, so I ended up creating a position_dodge object (is that the right terminology?), saving it to a variable, and then using that as the position for both geoms. <strike>Somewhat infuriatingly, they still seem to be a little off centre.</strike>

```
dodgewidth <- position_dodge(width=0.9)
ggplot(dat,aes(x = type,y = count, fill = group)) + 
  geom_bar(colour = "black", position = dodgewidth ,stat = "identity") +
  stat_bin(geom="text", position= dodgewidth, aes(x=type, label=count), vjust=-1)
```

[image]

Comment: MYaseen's method is centered.  Wonder if there's a fix to stat bin.

Comment: Yeah, I've just tried it with `dodgewidth <- position_dodge(width=0.9)
`, and it's nicely centered. I have no idea why 0.9 would be the magic number through

Comment: I don't think ther's anything special about 0.9. In the example below change the value for width in both the geom_bar and geom_text to see the effect.  I've just noticed the example is almost the same as MYaseen208

Comment: @SandyMuspratt With your example, using `geom_text`, the widths and dodges behave sensibly- you set the width of the bar, and then dodge the text by that amount. I still can't figure out how dodging works with `stat_bin` though, except I guess if 0.9 is the default width of a `stat_bin` bar and you can't really change it. `geom_text` is probably the better option in this case though, as you aren't really 'binning' the observations.

Comment: @Marius I'm not sure why dodging is not working for `stat_bin`. I've always used geom_text. Incidently in the geom_text example, there are other effects to be had. For instance, let the arguments for geom_bar() be: geom_bar(colour = "black",position = position_dodge(width = .8), width = .6)

Comment: @Marius Another incidently - your answer doesn't work - misplaced ! before the closing bracket.

Comment: @SandyMuspratt Thanks, I think it had snuck in at some point when I was adding the image to the post. All fixed up nicely now.

Answer (score 11):

**Updated**   `geom_bar()` needs `stat = "identity"`

I think this does what you want as well.

```
mtcars2 <- data.frame(type = factor(mtcars$cyl), group = factor(mtcars$gear))
library(plyr); library(ggplot2)
dat <- rbind(ddply(mtcars2, .(type, group), summarise, count = length(group)), c(8, 4, NA))

p2 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = type,y = count,fill = group)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", colour = "black",position = "dodge", width = 0.8) +
  ylim(0, 14) +
  geom_text(aes(label = count, x = type, y = count), position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), vjust = -0.6)
p2
```

[image]