# In ggplot, how can I print the count above only a specifc bar in a barplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I've found and been guided to numerous post showing how to place stats above all bars in a barplot in ggplot, but I haven't found one that shows how to only show the count/percentage above only one bar in the barplot.

- [How to put labels over geom_bar for each bar in R with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018499/how-to-put-labels-over-geom-bar-for-each-bar-in-r-with-ggplot2)
- [How to put labels over geom_bar in R with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455088/how-to-put-labels-over-geom-bar-in-r-with-ggplot2)
- [Annotation
  above bars:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327267/annotation-above-bars)
- [How to add percentage or count labels above
  percentage bar plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869862/how-to-add-percentage-or-count-labels-above-percentage-bar-plot/29871450#29871450)

For example with the following plot:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = gear)) + geom_bar() +
  geom_text(stat='count',aes(label=..count..),vjust=-1)
```

[image: mtcars barplot]

how could I just print "12" above the middle bar and supress printing "5" and "15". The bar I'd like to show the count above will vary from plot to plot (e.g. in another plot I'd like to show the stat above the 4th largest out of 5 bars).

Comment: That post and one it references only addresses putting values above all the bars. I would like to print those values only above specific bar in the barplot.

Comment: It's pretty much a duplicate of the cited link and two part questions are not encouraged on SO. So It's also _probably_ a duplicate as well and I'd encourage you to search for one and document your search before making any further appeal. You are _expected_ to search _before_ posting questions.

Comment: @42, revised per your suggestions. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Use a vector that contains `""` for the positions where you don't want values. And ... What about "How do I manually set geom_bar fill color in ggplot"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use stat() to calculate the count and define any condition you want for geom_text()

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Select the gear with the second highest count
g <- mtcars %>% group_by(gear) %>% summarise(n = n()) %>% arrange(rev(n)) %>% .[2, 1]

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = gear)) +
    geom_bar() +
    geom_text(stat='count',
          aes(label=stat(ifelse(x == !!g, count, NA))), # Apply condition
          color = "blue",
          vjust=-1) +
    NULL
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-10-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Much better answer than what I came up with. This should be the accepted approach.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find one that use geom_text r geom_bar but the examples in `?annotate` seemed pretty straighforward>

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=gear, group = gear)) + geom_bar(fill=c("red", "green","blue")) + 
     annotate("text", x=4, y = 13, label = "12")
```